# JavaFX How make a Node to be always in front and fully visible?

Tags: javafx, charts, javafx-2, z-index

This program generates a chart and displays the coordinate values when the mouse enters the plotted dots by replacing the dot for a label.

But the problem is that the label does not appear completely if the dot is in the border of the chart.

I couldn't solve this issue using the `toFront()` and `toBack()` functions.

My code was adapted from the answer to this question JavaFX LineChart Hover Values, which has the same bug.

Chart.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Chart extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    // Random chart
    // Defining the Axis
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    // Creating the chart
    LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

    // This didn't solve the bug
    xAxis.toBack();
    yAxis.toBack();

    // Preparing the series
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("Chart");

    for (double x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        double y = Math.random() * 100;
        XYChart.Data chartData;
        chartData = new XYChart.Data(x, y);
        chartData.setNode(new ShowCoordinatesNode(x, y));
        series.getData().add(chartData);
    }

    // Adding series to chart
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

ShowCoordinatesNode.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class ShowCoordinatesNode extends StackPane {

public ShowCoordinatesNode(double x, double y) {

    final Label label = createDataThresholdLabel(x, y);

    setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                setScaleX(1);
                setScaleY(1);
                getChildren().setAll(label);
                setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
                toFront(); // This didn't solve the bug
        }
    });
    setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                getChildren().clear();
                setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
        }
    });
}

private Label createDataThresholdLabel(double x, double y) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    final Label label = new Label("(" + df.format(x) + "; " + df.format(y) + ")");
    label.getStyleClass().addAll("default-color0", "chart-line-symbol", "chart-series-line");
    label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 10; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
    label.setMinSize(Label.USE_PREF_SIZE, Label.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    label.setId("show-coord-label");
    return label;
}
}
```

Comment: The chart looks to be clipping its content, which I wouldn't consider a bug. You could try using a `Tooltip` (a popup) and styling it; if using JavaFX 9+ you can set `showDelay` and `hideDelay` to  zero and `showDuration` to "infinite". The other option is to move the `Label` over the needed amount; you might need to rely on implementation details for that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a some searching trying to make this work and the reason toFront doesn't work as the Javadoc states

> Moves this Node to the front of its sibling nodes in terms of z-order. This is accomplished by moving this Node to the last position in its parent's content ObservableList. **This function has no effect if this Node is not part of a group.**

So I could not get that to work in any sense.  This is the only solution I could come up with it involves figuring out the width/height of the label/2 and shifting the label if it on the X or Y axis so you could see it

I made no changes in the Main other than hardcoding a testing value and removing the toFront Calls

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        // Random chart
        // Defining the Axis
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        // Creating the chart
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        // Preparing the series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Chart");

        boolean firstRun = true;//First point at 0,0 to test
        for (double x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
            double y;
            if(firstRun) {
                y = 0.0;
                firstRun = false;
            }else
                y = Math.random() * 100;
            XYChart.Data chartData;
            chartData = new XYChart.Data<>(x, y);
            chartData.setNode(new ShowCoordinatesNode(x, y));
            series.getData().add(chartData);
        }

        // Adding series to chart
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```

Here is where I added 2 If statements to translate the label if on one of the axises

```
public class ShowCoordinatesNode extends StackPane {


    public ShowCoordinatesNode(double x, double y) {

        final Label label = createDataThresholdLabel(x, y);

        setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            setScaleX(1);
            setScaleY(1);
            getChildren().setAll(label);

            if(x == 0.0) {
                applyCss();
                layout();
                label.setTranslateX(label.getWidth()/2);
            }
            if(y == 0.0){
                applyCss();
                layout();
                label.setTranslateY(-label.getHeight()/2);
            }

            setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
        });
        setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> {
            getChildren().clear();
            setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
        });
    }

    private Label createDataThresholdLabel(double x, double y) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
        final Label label = new Label("(" + df.format(x) + "; " + df.format(y) + ")");
        label.getStyleClass().addAll("default-color0", "chart-line-symbol", "chart-series-line");
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 10; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
        label.setMinSize(Label.USE_PREF_SIZE, Label.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        label.setId("show-coord-label");
        return label;
    }
}
```

I use the applyCSS() to calculate the size of the label before it is added to the window The JavaDoc states:

> If required, apply styles to this Node and its children, if any. This method does not normally need to be invoked directly but may be used in conjunction with Parent.layout() to size a Node before the next pulse, or if the Scene is not in a Stage.